# unable to connect to debian repos

Tags: debian, apt, deb

I have been getting the following from the last couple of days -

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://packages.riot.im/debian buster InRelease                                                                  
Err:2 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug buster-debug InRelease                                               
  Could not connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:80 (217.196.149.232), connection timed out
Err:3 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug InRelease                                            
  Unable to connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:http:
Err:4 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug experimental-debug InRelease
  Unable to connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:http:
Err:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Could not connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.8.204), connection timed out
Err:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
Err:7 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
Err:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease
  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done                               
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.8.204), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/unstable/InRelease  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/experimental/InRelease  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/dists/buster-debug/InRelease  Could not connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:80 (217.196.149.232), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/dists/unstable-debug/InRelease  Unable to connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/dists/experimental-debug/InRelease  Unable to connect to debug.mirrors.debian.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list -

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

                               #### Debian buster #########
        deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
        deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main


                              #### Debian unstable #########
        deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free


                           #### Debian experimental #########
       deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib
   deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib

                         ##### Debian Debug packages #######
       deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ buster-debug main
       deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
       deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main


                    ######## Third party repos #######
      deb https://riot.im/packages/debian/ buster main
     #deb https://lxqt.debian.net/debian  experimental-snapshots  main
     #deb-src https://lxqt.debian.net/debian  experimental-snapshots  main

    ########## Non-free ########
    #deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

FWIW, wget works normally as well as any other way to get big files.Even git pull works. Have no idea why I have issues. There doesn't seem to be a way to have it more verbose so we know what the issue is.

Comment: Seems like the issue I just asked a question about. Try disabling IPv6 temporarily (`sudo bash` then `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`). If that doesn't work, try `tracepath debug.mirrors.debian.org` to discover the correct MTU and check that your network interface MTU matches the figure tracepath outputs.